# Doesnt reference entity framework error at .NetCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have tried to use entity framework .netcore at visual studio 2019. But I have errors. I've added entity framework it says you don`t reference it. How can I fix it?

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmelj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .Net Core you need to install below Packages first

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

than

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

once both will installed than you need to run below command

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=servername; Database=databasename;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models.

to generate the Model as per database than you will get the all model classes in Models folder name with EntityContext than you can implement the Method in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Using EntityFramework; on top of the file. Also, don't use both EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFramework

Comment: I downloaded just EntityFramework and unisntalled EntityFrameworkCore. but it couldnt be solved. then I tried the opposite. but still the same